# Several flatmaps cause error on saving (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have Angular component to upload files to server.

Here is save method of it

```
 private saveFileAndData(): void {
    this._propertyService
        .createOrEditProperty(this.property)
        .pipe(
            flatMap(r => this._fileUploadService.uploadFiles(this.getUploadUrl(r), this.files)),
            flatMap(r => this._fileUploadService.uploadFiles(this.getFloorPlanUploadUrl(r), this.floorPlans)),
            finalize(() => {
                this.saving = false;
            })
        )
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.notify.info(this.l('SavedSuccessfully'));
            this.close();
            this.modalSave.emit(null);
        });
}
```

When I was having one flat map, all was okay, now I need to load different files via save. So I have 2 flatMaps. But now I have this error

[image]

If I leave just one flat map, all okay.

Here is fileUpload service

```
 @Injectable()
export class FileUploadService {
    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

    uploadFiles(url: string, filesToUpload: any[]): Observable<any> {
        if (filesToUpload.length) {
            const formData: FormData = new FormData();
            for (let file of filesToUpload) {
                formData.append('file', file);
            }
            let headers = new HttpHeaders();
            return this._http.post(url, formData, { headers: headers });
        }
        return of(null);
    }
}
```

How I can solve it?

Comment: from your screenshot , it seems like one of your uploadFiles calls have some wrong behaviour that makes the call to your upload endpoint with "null" !

Comment: yes, first one get id and second one get [object Object] @wessamyaacob

Comment: can you make stackblitz link demo to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: I guess no, because component is big and have much dependencies @wessamyaacob

Comment: try to add console.log(formData) before return this._http.post(url, formData, { headers: headers }); to make sure you are sending the correct parameters